# MVC3 Cannot access uncommon file types through GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quicktime

I am having an issue opening a sound file I have in the "Files" folder. The application uses GET to obtain the file, so I can test this in the browser. However the exact name and location in the browser throws a 404. If I rename the file to the .txt extension, it opens just fine (downloads).

The original file is a .caf file that originates on an iPad and through a series of transactions, using a web service as the pivot point, gets downloaded to the web server. Then the file gets opened with an integrated QuickTime player. In this current scenerio the QuckTime player is unable to open the file because the server returns a 404 when looking for it.

It seems to me that when I open files that are not of some standard format (txt, jpg, png, mp3) then it does not work. I have a feeling that this this comes down to routing, but I am not sure what exactly I need to add to the routing to get this to work.

NOTE:

This works just fine when testing on my local machine; however, when moved into a test environment the application is unable to obtain the file.

Comment: Check your IIS configuration.

Comment: Anything to look for in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the MIME type to IIS:

> Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) types identify the types
>   of content that can be served to a browser or a mail client from a Web
>   server. When a browser requests content from a Web server, the browser
>   also requests the MIME type of that content. IIS returns this MIME
>   type as the Content_Type field in an HTTP header before returning the
>   content, so that the browser knows how to process or display that
>   content.

Since you have a non standard file type, [you need to add it IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)